# How do I add a top level menu entry for my wordpress plug-in using a file?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I'm writing my first plug-in, more for learning than utility. I'm at the step of adding a menu settings page but I cannot get it to show. I have read that I should pass a callback function that will "print" the HTML used. However I wanted to pass a PHP file instead, that contains the relevant HTML and PHP code, howe woul I do? This is what I have so far:

```php
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'stwc_activation' );
function stwc_activation(){
    add_action( 'admin_menu', 'stwc_add_menu_entry' );
}
```

The the actual function that should add the menu and tell what PHP file to use to render the settings page:

```php
function stwc_add_menu_entry() {
    add_menu_page(
        'stwc',
        'stwc Options',
        'manage_options',
        'stwc',        
        array( SWTC_URL . 'includes/stwc_settings.php', 'dashboard' ),
        SWTC_URL . 'admin/images/swtc-icon.png',
        20
    );
}
```

I also tried this way, still no menu:

```php
    add_menu_page(
        'STWC',
        'Stimple Tools for WooCommerce - Settings',
        'manage_options',         
        SWTC_URL . 'includes/stwc_settings.php',
        '',
        SWTC_URL . 'admin/images/swtc-icon.png',
        20
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'stwc_plugin_init');

function stwc_plugin_init() {
    add_action('admin_menu', 'stwc_admin_menu');
}

function stwc_admin_menu() {
    add_menu_page('stwc Options', 'stwc Options', 'edit_posts', 'stwc', 'stwc_main_page', 'dashicons-admin-multisite', 4);
    add_submenu_page('stwc', __('Child Item'), __('Child Item'), 'edit_posts', 'stwc-child', 'stwc_child_page');
}

function stwc_main_page() {
   echo 'Main page';
   // Your code here
   exit;
}
 
function stwc_child_page() {
   echo 'Child page';
   // Your code here
   exit;
}
```

You can try like the above demo, steps to make it works:

- Add admin menus to action `plugins_loaded`
- Add `add_menu_page` for top level page
- Add `add_submenu_page` for child page

The result demo:

[image: Demo]

Comment: why use `plugins_loaded` instead of `register_activation_hook'?

Comment: @S.Redrum you should use `register_activation_hook` when that action happens the first time like add options, create new tables... With this case is add a menu, it will show every time you login into wp-admin, so `plugins_loaded` will keep it show always.

Comment: it worked! It shot me a huge icon, thought it was resizing it appropriately automagically.

Comment: @S.Redrum It's not auto resize. So you have to input a small icon, or you can use the icon from the WordPress library here https://developer.wordpress.org/resource/dashicons.

Comment: @S.Redrum Do you need anything else? If not, please accept this as an accepted answer :)) My pleasure to help you.